# Получить из одного массива другой по хитрой логике

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив:

```
arr1 = [
  {
    person_id: 1,
    fullName: "Иван",
    position_id: 01,
    position_name: "стажер",
    group_id: 001
  },
  {
    person_id: 2,
    fullName: "Марья",
    position_id: 02,
    position_name: "продавец",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 3,
    fullName: "Сергей",
    position_id: 03,
    position_name: "директор",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 4,
    fullName: "Василиса",
    position_id: 02,
    position_name: "продавец",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 5,
    fullName: "Юрий",
    position_id: 01,
    position_name: "стажер",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 6,
    fullName: "Ольга",
    position_id: 02,
    position_name: "продавец",
    group_id: 002
  }
];
```

должен получиться следующий массив:

```
arrResult = [
  {
    group_id: 001,
    groupData: [
      {
        position_id: 01,
        position_name: "стажер",
        persons: [
          {
            person_id: 1,
            fullName: "Иван"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    group_id: 002,
    groupData: [
      {
        position_id: 01,
        position_name: "стажер",
        persons: [
          {
            person_id: 5,
            fullName: "Юрий"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        position_id: 02,
        position_name: "продавец",
        persons: [
          {
            person_id: 2,
            fullName: "Марья"
          },
          {
            person_id: 4,
            fullName: "Василиса"
          },
          {
            person_id: 6,
            fullName: "Ольга"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        position_id: 03,
        position_name: "директор",
        persons: [
          {
            person_id: 3,
            fullName: "Сергей"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Я попробовал сделать это следующей формулой:

```
const result = Object.values(data.reduce((accum, item) => (
  (item.group_id in accum) ? '' : accum[item.group_id] = {
    'group_id': item.group_id,
    'group_name': item.group_name
  }, accum
), {}))
```

Что в целом позволяет мне сделать массив образца:

```
[
  {group_id: xxx, group_name: xxx, ...},
  {group_id: xxx, group_name: xxx, ...},
  {group_id: xxx, group_name: xxx, ...}
]
```

Но я не понимаю, как внутри reducer`a формировать еще и массивы и забирать из главного массива данные... Если кто-то поможет осознать, как сделать - буду мега благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Основная идея заключается в том чтобы сразу формировать нужный массив, в качестве позиций во всех массивах использовать id-1. Так как JS позволяет создавать элемент массива в любой позиции не зависимо от размера массива, то будут образовываться пустые элементы (null) которые потом можно отсеять фильтром.

Плюс данного подхода в том что практически за один проход выполняется и сортировка элементов и не используется метод массива find, что возможно скажется на скорости работы.

```js
const data = [
  {
    person_id: 1,
    fullName: "Иван",
    position_id: 01,
    position_name: "стажер",
    group_id: 001
  },
  {
    person_id: 2,
    fullName: "Марья",
    position_id: 02,
    position_name: "продавец",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 3,
    fullName: "Сергей",
    position_id: 03,
    position_name: "директор",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 4,
    fullName: "Василиса",
    position_id: 02,
    position_name: "продавец",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 5,
    fullName: "Юрий",
    position_id: 01,
    position_name: "стажер",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 6,
    fullName: "Ольга",
    position_id: 02,
    position_name: "продавец",
    group_id: 002
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((accum, item) => {
    // если нет группы создаем
    if (!accum[item.group_id-1])
      accum[item.group_id-1] = {
        group_id: item.group_id,
        group_Data: []
      }
    // если нет данных группы создаем
    if (!accum[item.group_id-1].group_Data[item.position_id-1])
      accum[item.group_id-1]
        .group_Data[item.position_id-1] = 
        {
           position_id: item.position_id,
           position_name: item.position_name,
           persons: []
        }

     // добавляем персон 
     //if (!accum[item.group_id-1].group_Data[item.position_id-1]
     // .persons[item.person_id-1])   
       accum[item.group_id-1]
        .group_Data[item.position_id-1]
        .persons[item.person_id-1] = 
          {
            person_id: item.person_id,
            fullName: item.fullName 
          }
    // удаляем образованные дыры в массивах
    accum[item.group_id-1].group_Data[item.position_id-1]
      .persons = accum[item.group_id-1].group_Data[item.position_id-1]
      .persons.filter(e => e != null)             

  return accum
},[])

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Comment: Отличный вариант :) (+)

Comment: Спасибо, я старался :) Но все нужно тестировать.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю такой вариант пойдёт.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {"person_id": 1, "fullName": "Иван", "position_id": 01, "position_name": "стажер", "group_id": 001},
  {"person_id": 2, "fullName": "Марья", "position_id": 02, "position_name": "продавец", "group_id": 002},
  {"person_id": 3, "fullName": "Сергей", "position_id": 03, "position_name": "директор", "group_id": 002},
  {"person_id": 4, "fullName": "Василиса", "position_id": 02, "position_name": "продавец", "group_id": 002},
  {"person_id": 5, "fullName": "Юрий", "position_id": 01, "position_name": "стажер", "group_id": 002},
  {"person_id": 6, "fullName": "Ольга", "position_id": 02, "position_name": "продавец", "group_id": 002}
];

let arrResult = []; // Хранить "форматированный" массив будем тут (далее буду называть его "возвращаемым")
arr1.map(e => { // Проходим циклом по массиву
  let group = arrResult.find(s => s.group_id === e.group_id); // Проверяем, есть ли уже в возращаемом объект с `group_id` ранвный тому, что в шаге цикла.
  if(!group) { // Если нет
    arrResult.push({ // То создаём запись
      group_id: e.group_id,
      groupData: []
    });
    group = arrResult.find(s => s.group_id === e.group_id); // Переназначаем переменную
  }
  
  // Далее аналогично, только для позиции
  let position = group.groupData.find(s => s.position_name === e.position_name);
  if(!position) {
    group.groupData.push({
      position_id: e.position_id,
      position_name: e.position_name,
      persons: []
    })
    position = group.groupData.find(s => s.position_name === e.position_name);
  }
  
  // А тут уже добавляем человека
  position.persons.push({
    person_id: e.person_id,
    fullName: e.fullName 
  })
});

console.info(arrResult);
```

Одно "но", различия только в сортировке, думаю если это важно, то проще пройтись ещё сортировкой поверх.

Answer (score 0):

Никак не хочу задеть тех, кто уже до этого ответили, каждый из ответ по своему удобен и логичен. Но лично для меня они не приемлимы.

Объясню, почему:

- В ответе `Daniil Loban` используется то что `id` представляет собой номер или строку, которая может быть представлен как номер и на этом завязана основная логика, что как по мне неправильно, т.к. `id` - это не обязательно номер, может быть и набором других символов, что не редкость. Но опять таки для данного конкретного случая - это рабочий, удобный и понятный вариант, который так же позволят не сортировать массив (но и то только если нужно отсортировать по возрастанию). Но даже с учётом этого `id` могут быть большими числами с большими разницами, что приведёт к огромному кол-ву пустых элементов, от которых надо отдельно избавляться, а так же, если `id` - это строка цифр, то нет гарантии, что не придут 2 элемента, где у одного `id` - это к примеру `'2'`, а у другого `'02'`. В таком случае один элемент перетерёт другой, что тоже неправильно
- В ответе `De.Minov` нет тех проблем, что присутствуют в другом ответе, но используется много `find`, что для мелких массивов никакой существенной разницы не имеет, но для больших данных - это будет заметно влиять на скорость

Алгоритм, который я предложу ниже, не содержит указанных выше минусов, но будет использовать больше объёма памяти, чем предыдущие алгоритмы, что так же может стать проблемой в каких-то случаях. Но как по мне, нынешние устройства, имеют достаточный объём памяти, чтобы я мог позаимствовать часть, для ускорения выполнения алгоритма. Ещё одним из минусов - это то что "магической" сортировки на месте как у `Daniil Loban` тут нет, потому надо будет отдельно сортировать массив, что более гибко. Ведь сортировка не обязана быть по возрастанию и не обязана быть именно по `id`, тем более каждый массив может понадобиться отсортировать по своёму ключу и порядку.

Основная идея будет заключена в том, чтобы свести поиск нахождения того или иного объекта в массиве к сложности `O(1)` путём создания "карты" массива в отдельной переменной. Как ключ в "карте" будет использовано `id` элемента, если такого нет, то можно составить для каждого элемента уникальную строку, основываясь на данных элемента, если, конечно, не будут два абсолютно одинковых элементов :) Но если есть риск, такого, то к ключу можно добавить что-то, например номер в массиве. Там уже по ситуации надо смотреть

И так сам код:

```js
const data = [{
    person_id: 1,
    fullName: "Иван",
    position_id: 01,
    position_name: "стажер",
    group_id: 001
  },
  {
    person_id: 2,
    fullName: "Марья",
    position_id: 02,
    position_name: "продавец",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 3,
    fullName: "Сергей",
    position_id: 03,
    position_name: "директор",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 4,
    fullName: "Василиса",
    position_id: 02,
    position_name: "продавец",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 5,
    fullName: "Юрий",
    position_id: 01,
    position_name: "стажер",
    group_id: 002
  },
  {
    person_id: 6,
    fullName: "Ольга",
    position_id: 02,
    position_name: "продавец",
    group_id: 002
  }
];

const formattedData = data.reduce((groupsData, el) => {

  const {groupsMap, groupsArr} = groupsData;

  if (!groupsMap.has(el.group_id)) {
    groupsMap.set(el.group_id, {
      map: new Map(),
      index: groupsArr.length
    });

    groupsArr.push({
      group_id: el.group_id,
      groupData: []
    });
  }

  const groupData = groupsMap.get(el.group_id);
  const positionsMap = groupData.map;
  const positionsArr = groupsArr[groupData.index].groupData;

  if (!positionsMap.has(el.position_id)) {
    positionsMap.set(el.position_id, {
      set: new Set(),
      index: positionsArr.length
    });

    positionsArr.push({
      position_id: el.position_id,
      position_name: el.position_name,
      persons: []
    });
  }

  const positionData = positionsMap.get(el.position_id);
  const personsSet = positionData.set;
  const personsArr = positionsArr[positionData.index].persons;

  if (!personsSet.has(el.person_id)) {
    personsSet.add(el.person_id);
    personsArr.push({
      person_id: el.person_id,
      fullName: el.fullName
    });
  }

  return groupsData;
}, {
  groupsMap: new Map(),
  groupsArr: []
}).groupsArr;

console.log(formattedData);
```

Буду рад конструктивной критике минусов моего кода, кроме тех, которые я сам уже указал